What will be the output of this C program?
int x=5,y;  y=++x++;  printf("%d",y);
What will be the output of this code and does it work?

There will be no output, but rather a compilation error, e.g. (on gcc): "error: lvalue required as increment operand". See demo.

Try running it first.  You should get a compile-time error.

Please provide more info on where you found that code and what makes you think that it can be compiled to create output. Is it possible that you made a mistake while copy-pasting? Is it possible that this is a trick question from an interview or a homework assignment or a test? Just in case, please have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

If the code compiled, then this question would probably be a duplicate of: Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?

One answer is that there is no reason to write code like this, and that you can use x += 2 to increase x in a single operation.

@chux-ReinstateMonica I think the dupe does not really fit this question, because here we do not have UB, but rather a compilation error due to invalid value category. Please consider to reopen.

The program will not have any output, since it will not compile.
The statement y=++x++; is actually parsed as y = ++(x++); due to operator precedence (postfix++ is higher than prefix++).
The postfix ++ (in x++) returns an rvalue, but it is fed into the prefix ++(...) which requires an lvalue operand (see: value categories, Increment/decrement operators).
gcc issues the following error:
error: lvalue required as increment operand

Live demo.
(note: as @EricPostpischil commented, the standard does not require the compiler to fail compilation, only issue a diagnostic. Common compilers will probably issue an error, although theoretically compiler specific language extensions might change that).
A side note:
There's an interesting difference between C and C++ regarding increment/decrement operators.
In C both prefix and postfix return an rvalue.
But in C++ prefix increment/descrement returns an lvalue.
Therefore in C++ you can use: y=(++x)++; (assigning 6 to y in this case).
This post is tagged C and therefore adding () either way will not change the result explained above.

In case the sidenote doesn't make it clear enough: don't compile C code with a C++ compiler. It often "works" but also often leaves programmers with misconceptions about C.

This code involves the pre-increment and post-increment operators, which can lead to some confusing behavior but I think there are a few issues with this code:
The expression ++x++ is not valid in C. It attempts to apply both pre-increment (++x) and post-increment (x++) to the same variable in a single expression, which is not allowed.
Even if it were allowed, the behavior would be undefined because it attempts to modify the variable x twice in a sequence point.
Because of these issues, this code will not compile and won't produce any output. Most C compilers will generate an error for this line.

Most likely the code will give error at y=++x++; in most of the compilers  But, if you want logical Explanation then,y=++x++;
will work as y=++x;  //y=6 and x++;  //x=7

Output:6

This is wrong. There can be no output whasoever for a program that fails to compile based on the language rules.

What do you mean by "this will work as ..." for code that, by your own assertion, will not compile? Do you mean that those compilers who disagree on the compilability will create code acting like that? What compilers do you have in mind? If none, what makes your think that compilers (especially standard obeying compilers) might act like that? Which part of the standard makes you think so?

@wohlstad: The rules of the C standard only require an implementation to issue a diagnostic message for this. They do not require that it fail to compile. C 2018 note 9 observes that an implementation “can also successfully translate an invalid program.”

@EricPostpischil fair enough. I wasn't aware of that but I'm sure you are correct in that distinction. But is there a point analyzing what should be the output of such a program ?

@wohlstad: Yes, this is one of the many ways in which C implementations may provide extensions to the base language. The C standard does not define only a restricted language that users of the language are required to confine themselves to. It defines a base language that is intended to be extended, by defining behaviors not defined by the standard, by adding new keywords, by linking in non-C routines, and more. Discussing what happens if we extend the language in some chosen way is reasonable.

@EricPostpischil I understand. But I thought that in this case it is not that probable (as it will require to turn an rvalue into an lvalue, or make the increment operator accept an rvalue). Am I wrong ? Anyway I added a note about it to me answer, refering to your comments.

@wohlstad: Yes, it is not portable, since that is the nature of extensions. (Until they are standardized and adopted, which is how we see standards evolving over time.) And extensions tend not to disrupt the language but to continue it naturally. A compiler that accepts ++y++ is probably not going to make it do a division operation but is likely to make it do two increments and add some sequencing so the behavior is defined in that implementation.

@EricPostpischil thanks for the info. I hope the note I added to my answer regarding this issue is satisfactory (especially given the fact that the OP did not mention any specific compiler or extension).
